# Update the progress bar after updating a like or dislike counter in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My progress bar doesn't update after making a change on my counter like or dislike.

I think it comes from my ternary condition where I add one to my like or dislike counter. After this, I didn't succeed to updating the state of "total" so it didn't updating the progress bar either.

First I receive likes and dislike from local data

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleClickLike = this.handleClickLike.bind(this)
        this.handleClickDislike = this.handleClickDislike.bind(this)
        this.state = {
          counterLikes : props.likes,
          counterDislikes: props.dislikes,
          liked : false,
          disliked : false,
          total : props.likes + props.dislikes,
        };
    }
```

I handleClick like and dislike

```
handleClickLike = (e) => {
        if(!this.state.disliked) {
            this.setState({
            liked : !this.state.liked,
            })    
        } else {
            this.setState({
            liked : true,
            disliked : false
            });
        }
    }

    handleClickDislike = (e) => {
        if(!this.state.liked) {
            this.setState({
            disliked : !this.state.disliked,
            })    
        } else {
            this.setState({
            liked : false,
            disliked : true,
            });
        }
    }
```

and my return where I've got the ternary condition and the progress bar who doesn't update after the condition done.

```
render() {

        return (

            <div className="like-dislike-container">

                <form>

                    <div className="likeDislike">

                        <span>
                        {this.state.liked ? this.state.counterLikes+1 : this.state.counterLikes}
                        </span>
                        <button
                        type="button"
                        id={this.props.id}
                        onClick={this.handleClickLike}
                        value="likes"
                        >Like</button>

                    </div>

                    <div className="likeDislike">

                        <span>
                        {this.state.disliked ? this.state.counterDislikes+1 : this.state.counterDislikes}
                        </span>                        
                        <button
                        type="button"
                        id={this.props.id}
                        onClick={this.handleClickDislike}
                        value="dislike"
                        >Dislike</button>

                    </div>

                </form>

                <progress max={this.state.total} value={this.state.counterLikes}/>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

It's important that I had to keep my like and dislike button to toggle. So that we can vote only for like or only on dislike and if we vote for one, we need to take off or vote to vote for the other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the way you are trying to increment the counters state inside the render() function instead of inside the click handlers and setState():

```
{this.state.liked ? this.state.counterLikes+1 : this.state.counterLikes}
```

and

```
{this.state.disliked ? this.state.counterDislikes+1 : this.state.counterDislikes}
```

In other words, the increments should happen inside the click handlers and set using setState().

How about making these changes? (Warning: I have not tested this, but you would get the idea)

```
    handleClickLike = () => {
        this.setState({
            liked : true,
            disliked : false
            counterLikes : this.state.counterLikes + 1,
            counterDislikes : this.state.counterDislikes - 1,
            total : this.state.counterLikes + this.state.counterDislikes + 1
        });
    }

    handleClickDislike = () => {
        this.setState({
            liked : false,
            disliked : true,
            counterLikes : this.state.counterLikes - 1, 
            counterDislikes: this.state.counterDislikes + 1,
            total : this.state.counterLikes + this.state.counterDislikes + 1
        });
    }
```

And then in your renderer:

```
render() {

    return (

        <div className="like-dislike-container">

            <form>

                <div className="likeDislike">

                    <span>
                    {this.state.liked ? this.state.counterLikes : this.state.counterLikes}
                    </span>
                    <button
                    type="button"
                    id={this.props.id}
                    onClick={this.handleClickLike}
                    value="likes"
                    >Like</button>

                </div>

                <div className="likeDislike">

                    <span>
                    {this.state.disliked ? this.state.counterDislikes : this.state.counterDislikes}
                    </span>                        
                    <button
                    type="button"
                    id={this.props.id}
                    onClick={this.handleClickDislike}
                    value="dislike"
                    >Dislike</button>

                </div>

            </form>

            <progress max={this.state.total} value={this.state.counterLikes}/>

        </div>
    );
}
```

Although, I should mention that your code can benefit from a good clean up. You could have implemented it in a much cleaner way. But the changes I made should hopefully resolve your issue.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for your answer. I tried this, so it's working but I didn't mentionned that I need my like and my dislike button to toggle. So that we can vote only for like or only on dislike and if we vote for one, we need to take off or vote to vote for the other. –

Comment: @ChristopheG, I updated the handler functions. Take another look. Also, if you need to be able to take off the vote completely, you can add the if statement back again. Please upvote and accept as answer if it helped. The idea is not give you the whole answer. Its about helping you find the answer!

Comment: I accepted the answer and upvoted it even my problem is not solved yet. I thank you for your help anyway.

Comment: @ChristopheG, what is the remaining problem?

Answer (score 1):

you are very close! The reason the progress bar is not updating is because this.state.total and this.state.counterLikes are being set from props. These props do not change when you call setState on the component, only when you call setState in it's parent component.

To fix this, recalculate the total and counterLikes in your handleClickLike and handleClickDislike functions and then add these new values to your setState call.

Comment: First I would like to thank you for your answer. I tried this, so it's working but I didn't mentionned that I need my like and my dislike button to toggle. So that we can vote only for like or only on dislike and if we vote for one, we need to take off or vote to vote for the other.